# Is there an accurate approximation of the acos() function?

Tags: opengl, glsl, precision, trigonometry

I need an `acos()` function with double precision within a compute shader. Since there is no built-in function of `acos()` in GLSL with double precision, I tried to implement my own.

At first, I implemented a Taylor series like the equation from [Wiki - Taylor series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) with precalculated faculty values. But that seems to be  inaccurate around 1. The maximum error was something about 0.08 with 40 iterations.

I also implemented [this method](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libm/Libm-315/Source/Intel/acos.c) which works very well on CPU with a maximum error of -2.22045e-16, but I have some troubles to implement this within the shader.

Currently, I am using an `acos()` approximation function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380628/fast-arc-cos-algorithm) where somebody posted his approximation functions on [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tcaty2sv8l) site. I am using the most accurate function of this site and now I get a maximum error of -7.60454e-08, but also that error is too high.

My code of this function is:

```
double myACOS(double x)
{
    double part[4];
    part[0] = 32768.0/2835.0*sqrt(2.0-sqrt(2.0+sqrt(2.0+sqrt(2.0+2.0*x))));
    part[1] = 256.0/135.0*sqrt(2.0-sqrt(2.0+sqrt(2.0+2.0*x)));
    part[2] = 8.0/135.0*sqrt(2.0-sqrt(2.0+2.0*x));
    part[3] = 1.0/2835.0*sqrt(2.0-2.0*x);
    return (part[0]-part[1]+part[2]-part[3]);
}
```

Does anybody know another implementation method of `acos()` which is very accurate and -if possible- easy to implement in a shader?

Some system information:

- Nvidia GT 555M
- running OpenGL 4.3 with optirun

Comment: why do you need acos? if it is for slerp you can divide and conquer with repeated lerps

Comment: there is a standard [acos](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/acos/) in `<cmath>`

Comment: Holy crap, use a lookup table if you need that many `sqrt`s.

Comment: @NathanOliver cmath is not available in a glsl shader

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I would use one, but this was just for the proof of concept. And as I said accuracy is more important then performance.

Comment: I'm wondering whether these approximations are actually faster... Did you ran any benchmarks?

Comment: why is this tagged C++ when the language is GLSL?

Comment: @CommuSoft I am not interested in the performance, so I didn't. I just tested the accuracy on the CPU against the implementation of acos() from math.h.

Comment: What are you using the returned angle for 9 out of 10 you can get to the result you want without acos

Comment: What's the range of arguments you need to support? [-1.0, 1.0]?

Comment: @RetoKoradi Yes. From -1.0 to 1.0.

Comment: @ratchetfreak To solve a complex equation in a kind of MLS algorithm.

Comment: What's your target hardware then?  GPU with Compute 1.3 or higher - NVIDIA cards GT200 and up, support double precision arithmetic.  I assume these functions have double precision too.

Comment: @Robinson I added the information to the question. In OpenCL and CUDA are double precision functions for 'acos()', but not within a shader. Unfortunately I am a bit restricted to compute shaders.

Comment: "I have some troubles to implement this within the shader."...such as?

Comment: Perhaps, (1) asin(x) = x + 1/2 (x^3/3) + (1/2)(3/4)(x^5/5) + (1/2)(3/4)(5/6)(x^7/7) + ...  (2) acos(x) = (pi/2 - asin(x)).  As a quick test, I got asin = 0.89726889283942934 with the stdlib giving 0.90384998229123237.  For acos(x) I got 0.67415967858914205 with the stdlib giving 0.66694634450366430.  Not sure how many iterations for it to converge to the kind of precision you want.

Comment: To add, there's a different way of calculating it around 1 because as you say it's inaccurate.  There's a question here about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20196000/own-asin-function-with-taylor-series-not-accurate

Comment: @Robinson Your first comment is exactly the Taylor series Ialready implemented. But i will have a look at the other question.

Comment: A different route is to [express acos in terms of atan](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2908908/express-arccos-in-terms-of-arctan); not sure that's better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My current accurate shader implementation of 'acos()' is a mix out of the usual Taylor series and the answer from [Bence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20196782/3223328). With 40 iterations I get an accuracy of 4.44089e-16 to the 'acos()' implementation from math.h. Maybe it is not the best, but it works for me:

And here it is:

```
double myASIN2(double x)
{
    double sum, tempExp;
    tempExp = x;
    double factor = 1.0;
    double divisor = 1.0;
    sum = x;
    for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
    {
        tempExp *= x*x;
        divisor += 2.0;
        factor *= (2.0*double(i) + 1.0)/((double(i)+1.0)*2.0);
        sum += factor*tempExp/divisor;
    }
    return sum;
}

double myASIN(double x)
{
    if(abs(x) <= 0.71)
        return myASIN2(x);
    else if( x > 0)
        return (PI/2.0-myASIN2(sqrt(1.0-(x*x))));
    else //x < 0 or x is NaN
        return (myASIN2(sqrt(1.0-(x*x)))-PI/2.0);

}

double myACOS(double x)
{
    return (PI/2.0 - myASIN(x));
}
```

Any comments, what could be done better? For example using a LUT for the values of factor, but in my shader 'acos()' is just called once so there is no need for it.

Answer (score 8):

The NVIDIA GT 555M GPU is a device with compute capability 2.1, so there is native hardware support for basic double-precision operations, including [fused multipy-add](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply%E2%80%93accumulate_operation#Fused_multiply.E2.80.93add) (FMA). As with all NVIDIA GPUs, the square root operation is emulated. I am familiar with CUDA, but not GLSL. According to version 4.3 of the [GLSL specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.30.pdf), it exposes double-precision FMA as a function `fma()` and provides a double-precision square root, `sqrt()`. It is not clear whether the `sqrt()` implementation is correctly rounded according to [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) rules. I will assume it is, by analogy with CUDA.

Instead of using a Taylor series, one would want to use a polynomial [minimax approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax_approximation_algorithm), thereby reducing the number of terms required. Minimax approximations are typically generated using a variant of the [Remez algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remez_algorithm). To optimize both speed and accuracy, the use of FMA is essential. Evaluation of the polynomial with the [Horner scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) is condusive to high accruacy. In the code below, a second order Horner scheme is utilized. As in DanceIgel's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28988233/780717), `acos` is conveniently computed using an `asin` approximation as the basic building block in conjunction with standard mathematical identities.

With 400M test vectors, the maximum relative error seen with the code below was 2.67e-16, while the maximum [ulp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) error observed is 1.442 ulp.

```
/* compute arcsin (a) for a in [-9/16, 9/16] */
double asin_core (double a)
{
    double q, r, s, t;

    s = a * a;
    q = s * s;
    r =             5.5579749017470502e-2;
    t =            -6.2027913464120114e-2;
    r = fma (r, q,  5.4224464349245036e-2);
    t = fma (t, q, -1.1326992890324464e-2);
    r = fma (r, q,  1.5268872539397656e-2);
    t = fma (t, q,  1.0493798473372081e-2);
    r = fma (r, q,  1.4106045900607047e-2);
    t = fma (t, q,  1.7339776384962050e-2);
    r = fma (r, q,  2.2372961589651054e-2);
    t = fma (t, q,  3.0381912707941005e-2);
    r = fma (r, q,  4.4642857881094775e-2);
    t = fma (t, q,  7.4999999991367292e-2);
    r = fma (r, s, t);
    r = fma (r, s,  1.6666666666670193e-1);
    t = a * s;
    r = fma (r, t, a);

    return r;
}

/* Compute arccosine (a), maximum error observed: 1.4316 ulp
   Double-precision factorization of π courtesy of Tor Myklebust
*/
double my_acos (double a)
{
    double r;

    r = (a > 0.0) ? -a : a; // avoid modifying the "sign" of NaNs
    if (r > -0.5625) {
        /* arccos(x) = pi/2 - arcsin(x) */
        r = fma (9.3282184640716537e-1, 1.6839188885261840e+0, asin_core (r));
    } else {
        /* arccos(x) = 2 * arcsin (sqrt ((1-x) / 2)) */
        r = 2.0 * asin_core (sqrt (fma (0.5, r, 0.5)));
    }
    if (!(a > 0.0) && (a >= -1.0)) { // avoid modifying the "sign" of NaNs
        /* arccos (-x) = pi - arccos(x) */
        r = fma (1.8656436928143307e+0, 1.6839188885261840e+0, -r);
    }
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The "problem" with `acos` is that it has singularities (branch points) at ±1, and for that reason Taylor or Padé won't approximate well.  The same applies to MiniMax approximations that try to minimize the max-norm when the domain contains a singularity.

The singularities are basically square-roots, so they can be factored out and the remaining function is smooth and approximates well.  The remaining function is `asinQ` in the C99 code that follows, it's a MiniMax rational approximation computed with the [Remez algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remez_algorithm). (The code is GNU-C99 actually so `M_PI` is available).

Notes on the code:

- The approximation minimizes the *relative* error because it's about floating point.
- It uses `sqrt` (square root), `fma` (float multiply-add), `ldexp` (scale by a power of 2)
- It uses `if-else` and conditional assignment. I am not familiar with shaders and whether that ruins the performance. If that's the case, maybe the code can be reorganized. Each path eveluates `asinQ` for some value 0 ≤ x ≤ 1/2.

```cpp
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static const double P[] =
{
    -5254.7508920534192751630665,
    +6236.4128689522053163220058,
    -2597.2384260994230261835544,
    +445.05537923135581032176275,
    -27.342673770163272135013850,
    +0.30325426599090297962612977
};

static const double Q[] =
{
    -5254.7508920534192747096309,
    +6674.3087766233233966852037,
    -3054.9042449253514128522165,
    +603.81083008747677276795370,
    -47.647718147243950851054008
    // 1.0
};

// Approximate arcsin(sqrt(x/2)) / sqrt(x/2) as MiniMax [5/5] over [0, 1/2].
static inline double asinQ (double x)
{
    double p = fma (P[5], x, P[4]);
    p = fma (p, x, P[3]);
    p = fma (p, x, P[2]);
    p = fma (p, x, P[1]);
    p = fma (p, x, P[0]);

    double q = Q[4] + x; // Q[5] = 1.0
    q = fma (q, x, Q[3]);
    q = fma (q, x, Q[2]);
    q = fma (q, x, Q[1]);
    q = fma (q, x, Q[0]);

    return p / q;
}

double my_acos (double x)
{
    double x_abs = x > 0.0 ? x : -x;

    if (x_abs <= 0.5)
    {
        return M_PI/2 - x * asinQ (ldexp (x*x, 1));
    }
    else
    {
        double x1 = 1.0 - x_abs;
        double ret = sqrt (ldexp (x1, 1)) * asinQ (x1);
        return x > 0.0 ? ret : M_PI - ret;
    }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double max_err = -1.0;
    double min_bits = 0;
    double max_x = 0;
    int ex = 8;
    if (argc >= 2)
        sscanf (argv[1], "%i", &ex);

    for (double x = -1.0; x <= 1.0; x += ldexp (1, -ex))
    {
        double err = (my_acos (x) - acos(x)) / acos (x);
        double bits = - log2 (fabs (err));
        //printf ("%+.6f: % 6e (%.2f bits)\n", x, err, bits);
        if (fabs (err) > max_err)
            max_err = fabs (err), min_bits = bits, max_x = x;
    }
    printf ("worst (%ld values): x=%+.6f, err=%6e, bits=%.2f\n",
            1 + (2L << ex), max_x, max_err, min_bits);
    return 0;
}
```

Running this for 16 Mio values prints

```
worst (16777217 values): x=+0.839781, err=5.803408e-16, bits=50.61
```

So the maximal relative error is around 6·10<sup>−16</sup> which is a precision of around 50.5 bits. (The absolute error for that value is 3.4·10<sup>−16</sup>.) Assuming `acos` and `sqrt` introduce an error of 0.5 ULPs, the precision of `my_acos` is around 1.5 ULPs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this solution helps.  It is better than 1% of the correct angle for x = 1 to 0.2.

acos(x) ~= sqrt(2) * ( sqrt(1-x) + (1/11) * (sqrt(1-x))^3 )

This started with a Taylor series provided by Wolfram.  That required too many terms for even a rough value below 0.8.  This method used the general form of the first 2 terms but changed the coeffs to improve the match.  Interesting that an integer coeff of an integer 11 worked.